# Delete all indexes of a table and rebuild them

Tags: sql-server

I need to delete all indexes (other than clustered index) of a table and rebuild them all.

For example, I have the following structure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SP6](
    [SP6_REGCLI] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [SP6_REGEMP] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [SP6_FILIAL] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [SP6_CODDEP] [char](9) NOT NULL,
    [SP6_DESCRI] [char](40) NULL,
    [SP6_FOLGA] [char](1) NULL,
    [SP6_HESOAU] [char](1) NULL,
    [SR_RECNO] [numeric](15, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__SP6] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [SR_RECNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [SP6_SR] ON [dbo].[SP6]
(
    [SR_RECNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SP601_1_REG] ON [dbo].[SP6]
(
    [SP6_REGCLI] ASC,
    [SP6_REGEMP] ASC,
    [SP6_FILIAL] ASC,
    [SP6_CODDEP] ASC,
    [SR_RECNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [SP602_2_REG] ON [dbo].[SP6]
(
    [SP6_REGCLI] ASC,
    [SP6_REGEMP] ASC,
    [SP6_FILIAL] ASC,
    [SP6_DESCRI] ASC,
    [SR_RECNO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

In this structure I have to delete all the NONCLUSTERED indexes (i.e. the index SP6_SR won't be deleted).

I need to do this because I have to change the size of some columns that is part of some indexes. For example, if I try to change the size of the colum SP6_DESCRI to Char(50) an error occurs because the column is part of index SP602_2_REG.

I think that if I delete all indexes of a table, change the size of columns desired and then rebuild all indexes, everything will be fine.

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Are you asking whether that is a fair approach so that you can write the code, or for code that would do it for you?

Comment: I'm using xHarbour language and I'm trying to change the column using a command like this: 

ALTER TABLE SP6 ALTER COLUMN SP6_DESCRI char(100);

Comment: To answer: "I think that if I delete all indexes of a table, change the size of columns desired and then rebuild all indexes, everything will be fine." - Assuming that nothing else is using that table, then it should be fine. Since you have already scripted out table definition, you can re-create those indexes.

Comment: I need to know how can I delete all indexes (other than clustered ones) of one (or more) tables. So I will change the columns and then rebuild indexes. I think it's possible but I don't know how to do it.